# How to save a part of streamed audio in android?

Tags: android, audio, save

Hello Everybody I'd like to ask u guys if someone called tell me how to save a part only of streamed audio in android and save as mp3 files or bytes.

Comment: What sort of stream? Can you post an example? What have you tried so far?